# Early bootup scheduling is extremenly fragile

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

As per init/main.c: setup_kernel

```
    /* Disable preemption - early bootup scheduling is extremely
 fragile until we cpu_idle for the first time*/
```

1. Why it is called fragile ? Any specific reason
2. What is its dependency on cpu_idle

Answer (score 1):

Preemption in kernel allows for kernel code to be preempted before it finishes. At the time, while scheduler is already starting, many portions of the kernel are not yet configured nor setup, so `start_kernel()` ensures that preemption is disabled even when it starts the timer interrupt which makes sure that the crucial setup tasks are not preempted before they finish.

Once cpu_idle task is running, if I read the source correctly, all necessary early initialization tasks are done and preemption can be reenabled.